# How to access the CURL to get the json data from php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, curl, https

How to access the CURL to get the json data from php.
By the way, I am using codeigniter framework.

This is curl data:

```
curl -u <YOUR_KEY_ID>:<YOUR_SECRET> \
-X POST https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders \
-H "content-type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "amount": 50000,
  "currency": "INR",
  "receipt": "receipt#1"
}'
```

and this my possible work to cosume it:

```
$url = 'https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders';
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        
        $data = json_encode(array(
            'receipt'=> $orderId, 
            'amount'=>$amount,
            'currency'=> 'INR'
        ), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
        
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type:application/json'
            //$keyId.':'.$secretKey
        ));
       
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Please help me to consume it!!
I am in trouble and also in hurry!!

Answer (score 1):

If the response like :

```
[{"data1":"value1","data1.1":"value1.1"},{"data2":"value2","data2.1":"value2.1"}...]
```

Use :

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);
$json   = file_get_contents('thelink', false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
$result = json_decode($json, true);
```

and call it like :

```
echo $result[0]["data1"];
echo $result[0]["data1.1"];
echo $result[0]["data2"];
echo $result[0]["data2.1"];
```

If you still want to use curl (example on weatherAPI) :

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/forecast.json?q=London&days=1",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "x-rapidapi-host: weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key: aaaaxxxxbbbb"
        ],
    ]);
            
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
            
    curl_close($curl);
            
    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        $weather = json_decode($response);;
    }
?>
```

Comment: the 1st option is if the api doesn't have ssl. If it have ssl then you can just remove the $arrContextOptions and what comes after the link in the file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I keep this for whenever I need to consume and API,

```php
$url = 'https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders';
$curl = curl_init();

$obj = new StdClass();
$obj->receipt = $orderId;
$obj->amount = $amount;
$obj->currency = 'INR';

$payload = json_encode($obj);

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
          'Content-Type: application/json',
          //$keyId.':'.$secretKey
      ), 
    )); 

    $response = curl_exec($curl); 
    $err = curl_error($curl); 

    curl_close($curl);
```

Get your response and handle any errors, maybe you are just missing a comma in your headers array